# How to get a select option by name and id

Tags: jquery

I have some select options by custom name like this:

```
<select class="amount" name="amount[17379]">
```

now, I would like to get each select option by id:

```
    var name_id = 17379 ;
    var _selector = 'amount\\['+name_id+'\\]';
    $('select[name="'+_selector+'"]').find...
```

but it doesn't work. where is my wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the slashes:

```
var name_id = 17379 ;
var _selector = 'amount['+name_id+']';
$('select[name="'+_selector+'"]').find...
```